# How to store credential or cookies for many sites

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, credentials

I wish to build a site more like Stack Overflow with a blog/page/apps for every member, and built with MVC 3. All features will be combined with different sites. How can I do this, or how Stack Overflow do it? Recently, if I remember correctly, I read that they did it with HTML 5...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the StackExchange sites including StackOverflow all use the OpenID authentication.

You can read a little about it on a recent codingHorror post about the [internet drivers licence](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/your-internet-drivers-license.html), or check out the [OpenID site](http://OpenId.net) directly. Its a simple concept, let the user use credentials that they already have.